# Elementary question about Langlands decomposition

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a a complex reductive algebraic group, together with an $\mathbb{R}$-form. Is it true that any continuous homomorphism $G(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^{\times}$ comes from an algebraic homomorphism $G \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$?

I ask this because I want to see whether in the Langlands decomposition $P = MAN$, if we start from an algebraic group $G$ the group $M$ is still algebraic ($M$ is defined as the intersection of preimages of $\{ 1,-1\}$ under all such homomorphisms $MA \to \mathbb{R}^{\times}$, where $MA = Z_G (\mathfrak{a})$ is a reductive algebraic group).

Edit: As was pointed out in the comments, of course the answer is negative. But then I modify the question, asking instead whether the intersection of kernels of $|\chi|$ for "algebraic" $\chi$ the same as for all continuous $\chi$.

Thanks

Comment: For $G$ semisimple, which is probably the key case to consider here, you should look at the classic paper by Borel and Tits http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0316587

Comment: No: compose any such "algebraic" one with the sign character on $\mathbf{R}^{\times}$, or instead (and even worse in general) compose it with $x \mapsto |x|^{1/29}$.

Comment: @nfdc23 : Oh, I see, of course you are correct. One still has the meaningful question though, whether the algebraic ones are "enough" (is the intersection of preimages of $\{ 1 , -1\}$ under the algebraic ones the same as under all).

Comment: Unfortunately still "no".  The problem is that $G(\mathbf{R})$ can be disconnected in complicated ways.  Its component group is an elementary abelian 2-group that can be quite large. When it is nontrivial then $G(\mathbf{R}) \rightarrow G(\mathbf{R})/G(\mathbf{R})^0 = (\mathbf{Z}/(2))^n$ composed with any $(\mathbf{Z}/(2))^n \twoheadrightarrow \mathbf{Z}/(2) = \{1,-1\}\subset \mathbf{R}^{\times}$ is nontrivial but kills the Lie algebra. This cannot be $\ker|\chi|$ for algebraic $\chi$, since if $\ker|\chi|$ is open then $|\chi|=1$ (as $\mathbf{R}_{>0}$ has no open subgroup of finite index).

Comment: Thank you, I will think about your comments. I guess that my question is because I want to work with algebraic groups, and understand things like Langlands classification. Then I want to be assured that if I start with an algebraic real reductive group, then the "$M$" from Langlands decomposition $P=MAN$ of a parabolic is also algebraic, so that I can use "induction". Otherwise, if I still insist to work with algebraic groups only, I will have to work with $MA$ and say things like "$L^2$ modulo center" etc.

Comment: Maybe references to the Borel-Tits theory of abstract homomorphisms don't help in your situation, but here is a more focused account by Tits: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0379749 (aimed at Lie groups, with some examples but without all details of proof).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now that the motivation for the question has emerged (algebraicity of $M$ inside $G$), here is how to handle it.  Let $G$ be a connected reductive $\mathbf{R}$-group, $P$ a parabolic $\mathbf{R}$-subgroup of $G$, and $S$ a maximal split $\mathbf{R}$-torus in $P$ (so $S$ is also maximal as such in $G$). We may and do choose a minimal parabolic $\mathbf{R}$-subgroup $P_0$ of $G$ contained in $P$ and containing $S$.

The set $\Phi(G,S)$ of nontrivial $S$-weights on ${\rm{Lie}}(G)$ is the (possibly non-reduced) relative root system spanning a finite-index subgroup of the character lattice ${\rm{X}}(S')$ for $S' := (S \cap \mathscr{D}(G))^0$ a maximal split $\mathbf{R}$-torus in $\mathscr{D}(G)$.

The choice of $P_0 \supset S$ corresponds to a positive system of roots in the relative root system, or equivalently a basis $\Delta$ of the relative root system, and there is a natural inclusion-preserving bijective correspondence between the set of parabolic $\mathbf{R}$-subgroups $Q$ of $G$ containing $P_0$ and the set of subsets of $\Delta$.  In this way $P$ corresponds to a subset $I \subset \Delta$. Explicitly, $U := \mathscr{R}_u(P)$ we have $P = L_I \ltimes U$ for $L_I := Z_G(S_I)$ with $S_I := (\cap_{a \in I} \ker a)^0$ a subtorus of $S$. Thus, $P(\mathbf{R}) = L_I(\mathbf{R}) \ltimes N$ for the group $N:= U(\mathbf{R})$ that is nilpotent (since $U$ is unipotent).

Let $A = S_I(\mathbf{R})^0$. If I remember correctly, Langlands' definition/construction of $M$ given the above choices is as the unique closed subgroup of $L_I(\mathbf{R})$ with compact center such that it is complementary to the central closed subgroup $A$ of $L_I(\mathbf{R})$. Your question is to show that $M = H(\mathbf{R})$ for a unique closed $\mathbf{R}$-subgroup $H \subset L_I$ with reductive identity component such that $M$ meets every connected component of $H$. Of course, such an $H$ is unique if it exists since its Lie algebra must be that of $M$ (so $H^0$ is uniquely determined in $G$) and it is generated by $H^0$ and any finite subset of $M$ meeting each of its finitely many connected components.  The real task is existence of such an $H$.

Define $H = \mathscr{D}(L_I) \cdot T_I \cdot S[2]$ where $T_I$ is the maximal anisotropic central subtorus of $L_I$.  Note that $H^0 = \mathscr{D}(L_I) \cdot T_I$, so $H^0$ is reductive, and $H(\mathbf{R})$ meets every connected component of $L_I(\mathbf{R})$ since $S[2](\mathbf{R})$ does (as $S$ is maximal split in the connected reductive $L_I$).  Since the connected reductive group $H^0$ is unirational, so $H^0(\mathbf{R})$ is Zariski-dense in $H^0$, the equality $H = H^0 \cdot S[2]$ implies that the center of $H(\mathbf{R})$ meets $H^0(\mathbf{R})$ in the subgroup of $Z_{H^0}(\mathbf{R})$ centralizing $S[2]$. Thus, to show $H(\mathbf{R})$ has compact center it suffices to show that $Z_{H^0}(\mathbf{R})$ is compact. But $Z_{H^0} = T_I$ by design of $H$, so $Z_{H^0}(\mathbf{R})$ is compact since $T_I$ is $\mathbf{R}$-anisotropic.

By design $H \cap S_I$ is finite, so $H(\mathbf{R}) \cap A=1$ since $A$ has no nontrivial finite subgroup. Thus, the multiplication map $H(\mathbf{R}) \times A \rightarrow L_I(\mathbf{R})$ is a closed embedding meeting every connected component, and hence this is an isomorphism if and only if the dimensions agree, or equivalently $\dim H + \dim S_I = \dim L_I$. Once this is shown, it follows that $H(\mathbf{R})$ satisfies all of the properties that uniquely characterize Langlands' construction $M$, so this $H$ would do the job. 
(Not only is the Lie group $M$ often disconnected, but $H$ is generally not connected as an $\mathbf{R}$-group, which is to say $S[2]$ is not contained $\mathscr{D}(L_I) \cdot T_I$; one sees this already when $L_I$ is a direct product of ${\rm{GL}}_{n_j}$'s.)

Since $L_I$ is the isogenous central quotient of the direct product of $\mathscr{D}(L_I)$ and the maximal central torus in $L_I$, in view of how $H$ was built it is equivalent to show that the split central torus $S_I$ in $L_I$ and the maximal anisotropic central torus $T_I$ in $L_I$ together generate the maximal central torus of $L_I$. In other words, is $S_I$ actually maximal as a central split torus in $L_I$?

Our task has now been reduced to something in the Borel-Tits structure theory for connected reductive groups over arbitrary fields $k$ as follows. Let $G$ be a connected reductive $k$-group, $S \subset G$ a maximal split $k$-torus, and $\Delta$ a basis of the relative root system $\Phi(G,S)$ of nontrivial $S$-weights on ${\rm{Lie}}(G)$. (This set of weights spans a finite-index subgroup of the character lattice of the maximal split $k$-torus $S' := (S \cap \mathscr{D}(G))^0_{\rm{red}}$ in $\mathscr{D}(G)$.) For a subset $I \subset \Delta$, define the $k$-subtorus $S_I = (\cap_{a \in I} \ker a)^0_{\rm{red}} \subset S$ and let $L_I := Z_G(S_I)$. The task is show that $S_I$ maximal as a central split $k$-torus in $L_I$.

By the centrality of $S_I$ in $L_I$ and the $L_I(k)$-conjugacy of all maximal split $k$-tori in $L_I$ (of which $S$ is one such), it suffices to show that no larger $k$-subtorus of $S$ is central in $L_I$. But $\Delta$ is linearly independent in ${\rm{X}}(S)$, so $S_I$ has codimension $\#I$ in $S$ and hence it suffices to show that the adjoint action on $S/S_I$ on ${\rm{Lie}}(L_I)$ supports $\#I$ linearly independent weights. But $I$ itself is such a set of weights in the subset ${\rm{X}}(S/S_I) \subset {\rm{X}}(S)$.

Comment: I agree that Hochschild's book is one of the few places to turn for detailed treatment of such questions.     Amusingly, it was published in an era when book publishers sensed that the world of higher mathematics was expanding rapidly, so I got a free copy then as an inducement to use it for a course (which I never had occasion to).     Better than getting just another free calculus or linear algebra textbook.

Comment: @JimHumphreys: I found Hochschild's book at the Strand in Manhattan. It is so rare to find such high-quality books in the math section of a bookstore anymore, at least in the United States. I don't remember what I paid for it, but certainly it was well worth the price.

Comment: @nfdc23: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Maybe I miss something; If $L = GL_n$ say, how can $M$ being the maximal compact work? It is not big enough to complement the center. Maybe your answer works only for minimal parabolic?

Comment: OK, I have now completely rewritten my answer so that it addresses the general case and not just minimal $P$. In particular, I no longer refer to Hochschild's book for the nice theory of maximal compact subgroups of Lie groups with finite component group. Instead, I use that the 2-torsion in a maximal split $\mathbf{R}$-torus meets every connected component of the group of $\mathbf{R}$-points of a connected reductive $\mathbf{R}$-group.

Comment: Hmm, given the motivation you may have wanted $M$ to arise from a *connected* $\mathbf{R}$-subgroup of $G$, or in other words to determine if $S[2]$ is contained in $\mathscr{D}(L_I) \cdot T_I$ (which is to say that the unique "algebraization" $H$ of $M$ inside $G$ is connected). In view of the uniqueness of $H$, it is the same to show $(\mathscr{D}(L_I) \cdot T_I)(\mathbf{R})$ meets each connected component of $L_I(\mathbf{R})$ (in which case we could avoid ever mentioning $S[2]$ at all). This question is intrinsic to $L_I$ and fails when $L_I = {\rm{GL}}_n$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I understand the main idea, I will try to think about the details.